# Calculating derivative by SciPy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Consider this python script

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0,1,100)

def y(x,z):
    return x**2 + z**-1 - 1

for z in np.arange(1,50,1):
    plt.plot(x, y(x,z))
```

At a fixed x, how can I draw

```
plt.plot(z, y(x,z))
plt.plot(z, y(x,z).derivative) #dy/dz
```

Comment: `y(z)` or `y(x, z)`?

Comment: @eyllanesc yes, `y(x,z)`.

Comment: What type of derivative do you require since according to indicas it is a 2-variable function?

Comment: Also correct the error `def y(z):` in your code and change it to `def y(x, z):`

Comment: @eyllanesc I think, since x is fixed, the partial derivative turns into an ordinary derivative. Right? I corrected the silly mistake. Thanks!

Comment: Did you work my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use the [`derivative`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.derivative.html) function:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from scipy.misc import derivative

x = np.linspace(0,1,100)

def y(z, x):
    return x**2 + z**(-1) - 1

z = np.arange(1.0, 50.0)

dydz = [derivative(y, zi, args=(x, )) for zi in z]
plt.plot(z, dydz)
plt.show()
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: You're calculating `dy/dx` instead of `dy/dz`, but I got your approach.

Comment: You are sure ?, I am calculating the correct derivative.

Comment: you're drawing `x,y` and its derivative at a fixed `z` (for every z). It should be `z,y` and its derivative at a fixed `x` (for every x).